# How to extract kext's from kernelcache?

Tags: kernel-mode, macos

I want to play with reverse engineering the Apple Neural Engine driver, which is a kernel extensions (`com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface`). These used to be in `/System/Library/Extensions/`, but on my M1 MacBook Pro with Sonoma (14.2.1) the `Extensions` directory doesn't include the binaries themselves, only metadata and resources.

Instead, all kext binaries are all bundled together in `/System/Volumes/Preboot/<...>/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kernelcaches/kernelcache`, as verified by `kmutil inspect -v --bundle-identifier com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface`.

How can I extract the binaries out of `kernelcache` file? Specifically I'm looking for the `AppleH11ANEInterface` binary.

The kernelcache file seems to be a IMG4 format, but existing tools like [pyimg4](https://github.com/m1stadev/PyIMG4) are failing to extract it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the ipsw tool from blacktop which specifically offers this functionality? https://github.com/blacktop/ipsw

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with [ipsw](https://github.com/blacktop/ipsw) @Jon mentioned. You just need to install it with brew, decompress the kcache

```
ipsw kernel dec /System/Volumes/Preboot/<...>/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kernelcaches/kernelcache -o <output dir>
```

then extract the kext you want:

```
ipsw kernel extract <path to kernelcache.decompressed> com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface
```